# Coxeter groups and Reflection groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, reference-request

What are some of the good books /Journals /Research Papers to study on Coxeter groups? Can someone suggest me a problem to work upon in this area or would a general survey on Coxeter Groups would be fine For the Master's Thesis?

Comment: Ask your potential advisor.

Comment: My advisor has left the choice of topic to me !!

Comment: That does not mean you cannot ask him for help in choosing or at least in providing you with some literature. He will have a much better idea about your background than random strangers on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Humphreys is a popular reference:

https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/reflection-groups-and-coxeter-groups/2910C1E00877D33A04A512791B6EDD72

Bjorner and Brenti is also really good if you're looking for something more combinatorial:

https://sites.math.washington.edu/~billey/classes/coxeter/EntireBook.pdf

Drew Armstrong is a great teacher, and he has some excellent course notes that I'd recommend as well:

http://www.math.miami.edu/~armstrong/685fa12.php
http://www.math.miami.edu/~armstrong/686sp13.php

As far as research problems, it's a big area so make sure to find something you're interested in.  I have three related conjectures on page 117 and 118 of [my thesis](http://www.math.miami.edu/~mckeown/thesis.pdf) that might not be too hard to prove (or disprove?...) Good luck!